# How to set currentIndex in BottomNavigationBar in Flutter from BLOC?

Tags: dart, flutter, rxdart, bloc

I would like to use a *StatelessWidget* with *BottomNavigationBar* which I would control from a BLOC. I can hook up the *body* of the *Scaffold* and *onTap* of the *BottomNavigationBar* to the BLOC (see the code). But I do not understand how one can set the *currentIndex* of *BottomNavigationBar* from BLOC (from Observable).

Is there any good solution or do I need to use *StatefulWidget* as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53019841/936780 which is similar to my example.

The BLOC code:

```
class Bloc { 
  final _currentTabSink = PublishSubject<int>();
  final _currentTabIndex = BehaviorSubject<int>();

  Observable<int> get currentTabIndex => _currentTabIndex.stream;
  Function(int) get setTabIndex => _currentTabSink.sink.add;

  Bloc() {
    _currentTabSink.stream.pipe(_currentTabIndex);
  }

  dispose() {
    _currentTabSink.close();
    _currentTabIndex.close();
  }
}
```

Widget code:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bloc = Provider.of(context);

    final List<Widget> _children = [
      AaWidget(),
      BbWidget(),
      CcWidget(),
      DdWidget(),
      EeWidget()
    ];

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(Localizations.of(context).appName),
        ),
        body: setBody(_children, bloc), // hook to BLOC
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: 1, // ?? how to hook up to BLOC ??
          onTap: (index) {
            bloc.setTabIndex(index); // hook to BLOC
            },
          items: [
            addAa(context),
            addBb(context),
            addCc(context),
            addDd(context),
            addEE(context),
          ],
        ));
  }

  Widget setBody(List<Widget> children, Bloc bloc) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: bloc.currentTabIndex,
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return children[snapshot.data];
        }
      },
    );
  }

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would need to wrap your `Scaffold` in a `StreamBuilder` with an initial data set and then you can access the snapshot data. Something like this (I had to make some changes to your code so it would build for me)

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bloc = Bloc();

    final List<Widget> _children = [
      Container(color: Colors.blue, child: Center(child: Text("1"))),
      Container(color: Colors.red, child: Center(child: Text("2"))),
      Container(color: Colors.green, child: Center(child: Text("3"))),
      Container(color: Colors.yellow, child: Center(child: Text("4"))),
      Container(color: Colors.orange, child: Center(child: Text("5"))),
    ];

    return StreamBuilder<int>(
      stream: bloc.currentTabIndex,
      initialData: 0,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Container();
        }

        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Test"),
          ),
          body: _children[snapshot.data],
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            currentIndex: snapshot.data,
            onTap: (index) {
              bloc.setTabIndex(index);
            },
            items: _children
                .map((child) => BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                    title: Text("Test"),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.black))
                .toList(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This works for me, the only downside here is that you will be rebuilding the `AppBar` unnecessarily every time the index changes.

Comment: This is the correct solution as I need to rebuild the AppBar as well, as it will contain actions which are tied to the index - when it changes they need to change. Thank you.